# Family of Closed/Open Nested Intervals

Tags: analysis

Find a family $\{I_n\}$ of closed nested intervals, such that no two $I_n$'s are equal and their intersection is $[-2,2]$.

An answer for the same question except for dealing with open nested intervals would also be appreciated.

Comment: What if you made $[-2,2]$ slightly larger?

Answer (score 0):

How about...

$$
I_n=\left[-2-\frac{1}{n},2+\frac{1}{n}\right],\quad n \in \mathbb{N}
$$