# Open Nested Interval Question

Tags: analysis

> Find a family $\{ I_n \}$ of open nested intervals such that no two $I_n$ are equal and the intersection is equal to $\left[-2,2\right]$.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650998/family-of-closed-open-nested-intervals) was asked earlier today.

Answer (score 2):

Let $I_n=(-2-\frac1n,2+\frac1n)$.